# I'm struggling with a proof that eventually lead to the Jacobi's transformation rule for Lebesgue integrals

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I need some help with a proof of a theorem leading to Jacobi's transformation
formula for Lebesgue integral (in the book Measures, Integrals and Martingales
from L. Schilling). What I need to prove is that for every $F_{\sigma}$-set $E
\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\left\{ \prod_{i
= 1}^n [x^j_i - \varepsilon^j, x^j_i + \varepsilon^j [\right\}_{j \in
\mathbb{N}_0}$ (a countable family of n-dimensional cubes in $\mathbb{R}^n$)
such that $E \subseteq \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}_0} [x^j_i - \varepsilon^j,
x^j_i + \varepsilon^j [$ and $\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}_0} \lambda^n \left(
\prod_{i = 1}^n [x^j_i - \varepsilon^j, x^j_i + \varepsilon^j [\right)
\leqslant \lambda^d (E) + \varepsilon$ (where $\lambda^d$ is the Lebesgue
measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$)

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Thank you, it should indeed be n instead of d, a small typo

Answer (score 0):

The author gives an explanation for that fact. The collection of half-open rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathcal{S}$, is a semi-ring. So, setting $\mu=\lambda^n$,
$$
\mu(E)=\mu^*(E)=\inf\!\left\{\sum_{j\ge 1} \mu(E_j): E\subset\bigcup_{j\ge 1} E_j,E_j\in \mathcal{S}\right\}.
$$
(See Eq. (6.1).) Now, by the [properties of infima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Properties), for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a sequence $\{E_j^{\epsilon}\}$ in $\mathcal{S}$ such that
$$
\sum_{j\ge 1}\mu(E_j^{\epsilon})\le \mu(E)+\epsilon.
$$

Comment: Ok but the $\{ E_i \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ in $\inf \left( \sum_{j \geqslant
1} \mu (E_j) : E \subseteq \bigcup_{j \geqslant 1} E_j, E_j \in \mathcal{S}
\right)$ are half open rectangles not half open cubes. The author mention then
that the halfopen rectangles can be subdived in halfopen cubes with sides of
equal size ($< 1$). I can see that you can divide a rectangle in a countable
set of cubes but not a finite set. So I was seeking for a more direct proof

Comment: I see your point. The passage that you mentioned is indeed not clear. However, $\mu^*$ can be alternatively constructed using [half-open (dyadic) cubes](https://books.google.nl/books?id=xPsXDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA73&dq=4+Outer+Measures+and+Sequential+Coverings&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKit_Bku3qAhXQGewKHQiOBgsQ6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: So if I understand it correcly, the strategy is to prove that $\inf \left(
\sum_{j \geqslant 1} v^n (D_i) |E \subseteq \bigcup_{j \geqslant 1} D_i 
\text{where $D_i \text{ are Dyadic cubes}$} \right) \text{ is equal to } \inf
\left( \sum_{j \geqslant i} v^n (R_i) |E \subseteq \bigcup_{j \geqslant i} R_i
\text{ where } R_i \text{ are rectangles} \right)$

Comment: The second construction gives a covering by cubes directly.